# Centering content within a full width row in Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Does anyone know how you would go about centering content on a full width row using Zurb's Foundation?

I currently have:

HTML

```
    <div class="row full-width nav-back">

        <div class="row large-12 column">

        <!-- CONTENT -->

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-back{
height:80px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,
color-stop(0, #004B91),
color-stop(1, #002952));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #004B91 0%, #002952 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #004B91 0%, #002952 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #004B91 0%, #002952 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #004B91 0%, #002952 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004B91 0%, #002952 100%);
```

}

This makes the content inside the "large-12 column" div stretch 100% the same as the parent container "full width"

Is there any way to center the content contained inside "large-12 column"?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the row in the nested column container?

```
<div class="row full-width nav-back">
  <div class="large-12 columns"><!-- CONTENT --></div>
</div>
```

It also might be that the `.full-width` is responsible for the 100% of the row. Usually the row has a max width, which centers your content when exceeded. In foundation docs its `max-width: 80rem;`. So you could try without full-width.

```
<div class="row nav-back">
  <div class="large-12 columns"><!-- CONTENT --></div>
</div>
```

With .large-centered you could also center the smaller column in a row, as 12 columns (large-12, medium-12, etc) usually are 100%.

```
<div class="row full-width nav-back">
  <div class="large-10 large-centered columns"><!-- CONTENT --></div>
</div>
```